# How to place an icon next to a string as an input value in an array of objects (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, icons

I am building a simple contact form in React and I am having an issue with the Submit button. I have built an array of objects to output the data for the contact form. My submit button is suppose to say `Send Message ->` with the font awesome arrow right icon. I have created a variable function for the icon but all I'm getting is `Send [object, Object]`. How can I get React to display the icon next to the text?

ContactFormData.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import {library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import {faArrowRight} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'


library.add(faArrowRight)


export const icon = () => {

    return (
        <div className="arrowRight">
            <Fragment>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRight} />
            </Fragment>
        </div>
    
    )
    
}




export const ContactData = [
    {
        label: "Full Name",
        placeholder: "Enter your full name",
        type: "text",
        id: "name",
        class: "input",
        value: ""
    },
    {
        label: "Email",
        placeholder: "Enter your email",
        type: "email",
        id: "email",
        class:"input",
        value: ""
    },
    {
        label: "Message",
        placeholder: "What are your plans?",
        type: "text",
        id: "message",
        class: "input",
        value: ""
    },
     {
        label: null,
        placeholder: null,
        type: "button",
        id: "button",
        class: "fas fa-arrow-right",
        value: "Send Message " + icon()
    }
]
```

ContactForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {ContactData} from './ContactFormData'
import './Contact.css'
import './Archivo-Regular.ttf'


class ContactForm extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="contactFormContainer">

                    {ContactData.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                        <form key={index}>

                            <label>{item.label}</label>
                            <br/>
                                <input type= {item.type} placeholder={item.placeholder} 
                                       value={item.value}
                                       className={item.class}id={item.id}/>

                        </form>
                        )
                    })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default ContactForm
```

Comment: Do you really want to repeat the form tag in your HTML? As per your code right now you will have multiple form tags in your in your HTML code. I would suggest you to run the map function before input tag and you can call the button separately

Comment: It doesn't repeat if the input type is set as a button. Calling the button separately will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to repeat form tag for each input field. To make it work move form tag one level upper, as a wrapper. Then - loop through input fields as defined in separate file.
My suggestion is to add submit button separately, as a part of ContactForm (it has a different purpose than other fields - holds no value, etc)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {ContactData} from './ContactFormData'
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {faArrowRight} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import {library} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import './Contact.css'
import './Archivo-Regular.ttf'


library.add(faArrowRight)

class ContactForm extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="contactFormContainer">
                <form>
                    {ContactData.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <>
                                <label>{item.label}</label>
                                <br />
                                <input type={item.type} placeholder={item.placeholder} value={item.value} className={item.class} id={item.id}/>
                            </>
                        )
                    })}
                    <button type="submit">
                        Send Message <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRight} />
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default ContactForm;
```